# How to access a "plone site object" without context?

Tags: plone, zope

I have a scheduled job (i'm using `apscheduler.scheduler` lib) that needs access to the plone site object, but I don't have the context in this case. I subscribed `IProcessingStart` event, but unfortunately `getSite()` function returns `None`.

Also, is there a programmatic way to obtain a specific Plone Site from Zope Server root?

Additional info:

I have a job like this:

```
from zope.site import hooks

sched = Scheduler()

@sched.cron_schedule(day_of_week="*", hour="9", minute="0")
def myjob():
    site = hooks.getSite()
    print site
    print site.absolute_url()
    catalogtool = getToolByName(site, "portal_catalog")
    print catalogtool
```

The `site` variable is always `None` inside a APScheduler job. And we need informations about the site to run correctly the job.

We have avoided to execute using a public URL because an user could execute the job directly.

Comment: How exactly are you running the job against the Plone site? Why not execute a certain URL in the site?

Comment: Hi, Martijn. I add some informations and tried to answer your questions.

Is there a way to `getSite()` return a valid value (a site object) without opening a ZODB connection, as indicated in your answer below?

Comment: No, you cannot *have* a site without loading it from somewhere. I am not familiar with APScheduler, but if it involves a separate thread to execute the scheduled job, then you need to open a new ZODB connection and load the Plone site from there, calling `setSite()` with that object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Build a context first with `setSite()`, and perhaps a request object:

```
from zope.app.component.hooks import setSite
from Testing.makerequest import makerequest

app = makerequest(app)
site = app[site_id]
setSite(site)
```

This does require that you open a ZODB connection yourself and traverse to the site object yourself.

However, it is not clear *how* you are accessing the Plone site from your scheduler. Instead of running a full new Zope process, consider calling a URL from your scheduling job. If you integrated APScheduler into your Zope process, you'd have to create a new ZODB connection in the job, traverse to the Plone site from the root, and use the above method to set up the site hooks (needed for a lot of local components anyway).